# delete the spaces that appear between rows when I print the table

Tags: css, laravel

The problem I face occurs when the Summernote tool has a lot of data inside the table to be printed, so a large empty space appears in the middle of the report... Please help to not showing this empty space when printing`

```
@extends('layouts.app')
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/views_css/header_heartbeat.css') }}">

<style>
/* .note-editable{
    font-size: 0.5vw
} */
.fit-content-card {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
      
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
        
    }
    /* setting the text-align property to center*/
     td {
      padding: 5px;
      text-align:center;
            
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto; 
    }
    hr {
        border-top: 3px solid black;
    }

    @media print {
        body {
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        background-color: white !important;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .header, .main-footer, .mb-2{
            display: none;
        }
        .content-wrapper{
        margin: 0 !important;
        background-color: white !important;
         }
       .main-sidebar{
        display: none !important;
        }
        table, th, td {
        border: 2px solid black !important;
    }
    }

</style>

@section('title')
{{__('عرض كارتيلة الموديل')}}
@endsection

@section('content')
<section class="content-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h1 class="heart-beat">
            <i class="fas fa-text-height"></i>
            عرض كارتيلة الموديل
            </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">

        <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm float-left" href="{{ route('cartila_report') }}">
        رجوع
        </a>

        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm float-left" onclick="window.print()" style="margin-left: 10px;"> 
            <i class="fas fa-print"></i>
            طباعه 
        </button>

        <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm float-left" href="{{ URL('model_update/'.$result[0]->id) }}">
            التعديلات السابقه
            </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>

    <div class="content px-3">

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="card fit-content-card">
            <div class="card-body">

                
                <div align="center">
                    <table style="background-color:#ffffff; width: 100%;height: 100%;"  dir="ltr" id="contnet">
                        @foreach($result as $results)
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"  style="text-align: center">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('uploads/logo.png') }}" style="width: 120px ;height:85px"> </td>
                                <td colspan="3" rowspan="2"  style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: 900">كارتلـــة تشغيــل موديـــل</td>
                                <td width="133"><b>الشام فاشون </b> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="133" style=" font-weight: 900">
                                إدارة التخطيط
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td rowspan="6" colspan="2">
                                تكتت مقاسات اسيتات مطبوع </td>
                                <td rowspan="3" style="font-size: 30px" width="193">صاله ( 1 ) </td>
                                <td width="488" colspan="2" >
                                    {{$results->cartila_date}}
                                </td>
                                <td width="133">
                               <b>تاريخ الانشاء </b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>

                                <td width="488" height="24" colspan="2">
                                    <?php
                                    $date = new DateTime($results->cartila_date);
                                    $dayName = $date->format('l'); // 'l' format gives the full day name in the current locale
                                    // Arabic day names
                                    $arabicDayNames = ['Monday' => 'الاثنين','Tuesday' => 'الثلاثاء','Wednesday' => 'الأربعاء','Thursday' => 'الخميس',
                                                        'Friday' => 'الجمعة','Saturday' => 'السبت','Sunday' => 'الأحد',];
                                    // Translate the day name to Arabic
                                    $arabicDayName = $arabicDayNames[$dayName];
                                    echo $arabicDayName;
                                    ?>
                                </td>

                                <td height="24" width="133" >
                               <b>اليوم</b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="488" colspan="2">
                                    <span class="badge badge-info" style="font-size: 14px ; width: 50px;">
                                        {{$results->model_code}}
                                    </span> </td>
                                <td width="133" >
                               <b> رقم الموديل </b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td rowspan="2" style="font-size: 30px" width="193">خط (  1  )</td>
                                <td width="488" colspan="2" >
                                    {{$results->get_finalproduct->name}} </td>
                                <td width="133" >
                               <b>نوع الموديل </b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="488" colspan="2">
                                    {{$results->get_customer->name}} </td>
                                <td width="133">
                               <b>العميل</b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3" style="font-size: 30px; text-align: center;">
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        @php
                                        $processedQuantities = [];
                                    @endphp
                                    
                                    @foreach ($results->get_cloth_thread as $cloth_quantity)
                                        @if (!in_array($cloth_quantity->quantity, $processedQuantities))
                                            @php
                                                $processedQuantities[] = $cloth_quantity->quantity;
                                            @endphp
                                    
                                            <div class="form-group text-center" style="border-left: 1px solid #000; border-right: 1px solid #000; margin-bottom: 0px">
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;{{$cloth_quantity->quantity}} قطعه &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            </div>
                                        @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                    
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td ><b>الكميه</b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                @if(isset($results->model_fit))
                                <td width="100" >
                                    {{$results->ticket_in_out}}  {{--  اسيتات --}}
                              </td>
                              <td style="font-weight: 900; background-color: rgb(5, 189, 81); font-size:14px;"> {{--  التلبيس --}}
                                {{$results->model_fit}}  {{--التلبيس--}}  
                              </td> 
                              @else
                              <td width="100" colspan="2">
                                {{$results->ticket_in_out}}  {{--  اسيتات --}}
                          </td>
                              @endif

                                    <td colspan="3" style="font-size: 30px">
                                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                            @php
                                            $processedIds = [];
                                        @endphp
                                        
                                        @foreach ($results->get_cloth_thread as $cloth_quantity)
                                            @foreach ($cloth_quantity->get_product_color as $item)
                                                @if (!in_array($item->id, $processedIds))
                                                    @php
                                                        $processedIds[] = $item->id;
                                                    @endphp
                                        
                                                    <div class="form-group text-center" style="border-left: 1px solid #000; border-right: 1px solid #000;margin-bottom: 0px">
                                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;{{$item->get_product->name}} 
                                        
                                                        @if($item->color_id == 894)
                                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        @elseif($item->get_color->name == 'بدون كود')
                                                            {{$item->get_color->invcolor_category->name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        @else
                                                            {{$item->get_color->name}} {{$item->get_color->invcolor_category->name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        @endif
                                                    </div>
                                                @endif
                                            @endforeach
                                        @endforeach
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    

                                    <td><b>الخامه</b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style=" vertical-align: top;">
                                    <br>
                                    <div>
                                        <h5>
                                            صورة الموديل
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                    @foreach ($results->get_model_image as $images)
                                <div>
                                <img width="210" height="190" src="{{ asset('uploads/models/' . $images->img) }}">
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                @endforeach
                                <div>
                                <hr style="border-top: 3px solid black;">
                                الخيط الخارجي 
                                <hr style="border-top: 3px solid black;">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                     @foreach ($results->get_model_thread as $thread_out)
                            @foreach ($thread_out ->get_thread_out as $item)
                        
                                    <div class="form-group text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
                                        {{$item->get_product->name}} 
                        
                                        @if($item->color_id == 894)
                                         
                                        @elseif($item->get_color->name == 'بدون كود')
                                            {{$item->get_color->invcolor_category->name}}
                                        @else
                                             {{$item->get_color->invcolor_category->name}}_{{$item->get_color->name}}
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                            @endforeach
                        @endforeach
                                </div>
                            </td>
    {{---------------------------------- Start stage ---------------------------}}

                                <td  colspan="4" >
                                    <h2 style="color: rgb(46, 46, 46); background-color: powderblue;">
                                        <b>{{$results->model_name}}</b>
                                    </h2>
                                  
                                    @foreach ($results->get_model_stage as $stages)
                                    <h3 style=" border: 5px solid rgb(90, 90, 90);  text-align:center; padding-bottom:7px">  {{$stages->get_stage->name}}   </h3>
                                 
                                    <textarea  class="textareacartila" >
                                        {{$stages->description}}
                                    </textarea>
                                    @endforeach
                               
    {{---------------------------------- ENd stage ---------------------------}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="240" colspan="2" style="background-color: rgb(255, 238, 0)">
                                  الاكسسوار</td>

                                <td width="240" style="background-color: rgb(255, 238, 0)">
                                  الخيوط الداخليه</td>

                                <td width="198" style="background-color: rgb(255, 238, 0)">
                                   الخيوط الخارجيه</td>

                                <td width="171" style="background-color: rgb(255, 238, 0)">
                                   الخامة</td>

                                <td width="133" style="background-color: rgb(255, 238, 0)">
                                 تحريف الصدر و الظهر</td>
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                            <td width="240" colspan="2" style="background-color: rgb(20, 118, 143)">
                                <b>
                                مع العميل
                                </b>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="3">
                               {{-- بدايه الخيوط الداخليه --}}
                           {{-- بدايه الخيوط الداخليه --}}
                           <div class="row">
                               {{-- الخيوط الداخلية --}}
                               <div class="col border border-dark d-flex flex-column">
                                   @foreach ($results->get_model_thread as $thread_in)
                                       @foreach ($thread_in->get_thread_in as $item)
                                       <div class="form-group text-center flex-grow-1 @if(!$loop->last || !$loop->parent->last) border-bottom border-dark @endif">
                                               {{$item->get_product->name}}
                                               @if($item->color_id == 894)
                                               @elseif($item->get_color->name == 'بدون كود')
                                                   {{$item->get_color->invcolor_category->name}}
                                               @else
                                                   {{$item->get_color->invcolor_category->name}}_{{$item->get_color->name}}
                                               @endif
                                           </div>
                                       @endforeach
                                   @endforeach
                               </div>
                           
                               {{-- الخيوط الخارجية --}}
                               <div class="col border border-dark d-flex flex-column">
                             @foreach ($results->get_model_thread as $thread_out)
                            @foreach ($thread_out->get_thread_out as $item)
                            <div class="form-group text-center flex-grow-1 @if(!$loop->last || !$loop->parent->last) border-bottom border-dark @endif">
                                    {{$item->get_product->name}}
                                    @if($item->color_id == 894)
                                    @elseif($item->get_color->name == 'بدون كود')
                                        {{$item->get_color->invcolor_category->name}}
                                    @else
                                        {{$item->get_color->invcolor_category->name}}_{{$item->get_color->name}}
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                        @endforeach
                    </div>

                    {{-- الخامه --}}
                       <div class="col border border-dark d-flex flex-column">
                        @foreach ($results->get_model_thread as $index => $cloth_quantity)
                            @foreach ($cloth_quantity->get_cloth_thread->get_product_color as $key => $item)
                                   <div class="form-group text-center flex-grow-1 @if(!$loop->last || !$loop->parent->last) border-bottom border-dark @endif">
                                   {{$item->get_product->name}}
                                   @if($item->color_id == 894)
                                    @elseif($item->get_color->name == 'بدون كود')
                                    {{$item->get_color->invcolor_category->name}}
                                      @else
                                         {{$item->get_color->invcolor_category->name}}_{{$item->get_color->name}}
                                       @endif
                                       </div>
                                        @endforeach
                                       @endforeach
    
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                            </td>
                            {{-- END   الخامه --}}

                                <td  >
               التحويل بالمتر
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="240" colspan="2" >
                                    الاجمالي
                                </td>

                                <td colspan="3" >
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        @foreach ($results->get_ratio as $ratios)
                                        <div class="form-group col-1 text-center" style="border-left: 1px solid #000; border-right: 1px solid #000;margin-bottom: 0px">
                                        {{$ratios->get_size_finalproducts->name}}
                                        </div>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td width="133" >
                                    المقاسات
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="240" colspan="2" >
                                    {{ $results->get_ratio->sum('ratio') }}
                                    </td>

                                <td  colspan="3" >
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        @foreach ($results->get_ratio as $ratios)
                                        <div class="form-group col-1 text-center" style="border-left: 1px solid #000; border-right: 1px solid #000;margin-bottom: 0px">
                                       {{$ratios->ratio}}
                                        </div>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td width="133" >
                                    الريشيو
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach 

                            <tr>
                                <td width="240" colspan="6" >
                                    
                                   <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3 text-center" >
                                                <span> طول ماركر الجسم :</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3 text-center" >
                                                <span> طول ماركر البفتة :</span>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-3 text-center" >
                                            <span>   استهلاك القطعه :</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-3 text-center" >
                                            <span>   استهلاك القطعه :</span>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                </td>


                            </tr>

                            </table>
                    </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

@endsection


<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.textareacartila').prop("disabled", true);
        $('.textareacartila').summernote({
            toolbar: [],
            disableResizeEditor: true,
            readOnly: true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem I face occurs when the Summernote tool has a lot of data inside the table to be printed, so a large empty space appears in the middle of the report... Please help to not showing this empty space when printin